# Google Sheets registering blank cell as zero

Tags: google-sheets

I am writing a formula into google sheets and I do not want the formula to register a blank cell as zero. The formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(A:A=H12, (D:D-C:C))))
```

It keeps giving me a zero value because some of the cells are blank. It is a monthly sales spreadsheet, so I don't have all of the data until the month is finished, but I'd like to have it working until I enter in all of the information.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to add criteria to exclude those in Columns D and C that are blank:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF((A:A=H12)*(D:D<>"")*(C:C<>""), (D:D-C:C))))
```

The `*` acts like `AND`.  So all three need to resolve to `TRUE` for it to consider the array in the MIN().

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(A:A=H12,IF(D:D="","",IF(C:C="","",D:D-C:C))))
```

The quotations directly after the D in the formula instruct to look for a blank value in column D first. The comma signifies next instructions on what to return if the logic test is true (if it finds a blank); the next quotations is the value blank desired to be filled in if so. 
This step is repeated for column C and finally is the instructions of what to do if either is void of blanks.

A IFS function could have been used but I felt using individual IF functions better demonstrated the concept of the logic test.