# How to use AND with a symbol instead of a function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I know that we can use the AND function to create conditions based off of more than one criteria:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>"", B2=""), "You are missing a last name", "")
```

However, in SQL and programming we can specify AND with `&&` and OR with `||`. This makes expressions easier to parse, especially when you have a bunch of conditions chained together:

```
=IF(A2<>"" && B2="", "You are missing a last name", "")
```

When I try the above, it shows the error:

> Formula parse error.

Is there a symbol we can use for AND and OR instead of the functions in Google Sheets?

---

The reason I suspect there might be a symbol is because instead of `CONCATENATE`, they allow you to use the `&` symbol:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2, B2, C2)
```

Is the same as:

```
=A2 & B2 & C2
```

Thus I suspect there might be a succinct way to specify AND and OR conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=IF((A2<>"") * (B2=""), "You are missing a last name", "")
```

Google Sheets hasn't a symbol for `AND` and `OR` functions but you can use `*` and `+` respectively as `TRUE` is *coerced* to number as `1` and `FALSE` is *coerced* to number as `0`, also any number not igual to `0` is treated as `TRUE` and `0` is treated as `FALSE` on a Boolean argument as the first argument of `IF`.

[image]

---

Q/A using * or + instead or AND and OR

- [Google Sheets registering blank cell as zero](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95743/88163)
- [Totally confused by my arrayformula(IF+FILTER+IF) function](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109801/88163)
- [Is it possible arrayformula combined with many if, and, isblank?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/148045/88163)

---

Resources

- [Type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion)